# Need help reordering month

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am trying to create a graph of unemployment rates in Illinois for each month. My data table is simple. It looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
unemploy_data_il <- read.csv("data/clean_data/unemploy_rate_il_2020.csv")

library("ggplot2")

unemployment_il_graph <- ggplot(unemploy_data_il, aes(x = month,
                                                      y = unemployment_rate)) +
  geom_point()
print(unemployment_il_graph)
```

However, when I run my code, the months on the graph is alphabetize and not actually in order as I have them in my data table. What should I do to fix this?

My graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at how to properly share your data and make your question reproducible, end edit your question appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. But this is probably a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph.

Comment: this didn't help at all